# Sequelize many-to-many M:N relationship not functioning. Error: 'SequelizeEagerLoadingError:${model1} is not associated to ${model2}'

Tags: sequelize.js, many-to-many, associations, eager-loading, junction-table

I'm trying to make a many to many relationship between users and roles through a predefined table roleUsers.

```
const User = sequelize.define('User', {
    firstName: DataTypes.STRING,
    lastName: DataTypes.STRING,
    email: DataTypes.STRING,
    phone: DataTypes.STRING,
    password: DataTypes.STRING,
    deletedAt: DataTypes.DATE,
  },

  const Role = sequelize.define('Role', {
    roleName: DataTypes.STRING,
  }, 

  const RoleUser = sequelize.define('RoleUser', {
    userId: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      references: {
        model: User,
        key: 'id',
      },
    },
    roleId: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      references: {
        model: Role,
        key: 'id',
      },
    },
  },

  Role.belongsToMany(User, {
    through: RoleUser,
    foreignKey: 'roleId',
    otherKey: 'userId',
    as: 'users',
  });
  User.belongsToMany(Role, {
    through: RoleUser,
    foreignKey: 'userId',
    otherKey: 'roleId',
    as: 'roles',
  });
```

However when I try to call this relationship (or any other M:N relationship - 1:Ms and 1:1s are working fine) as below

```
    const roles = await Role.findAll({
      include: [
        {
          model: User,
          as: 'users',
          through: RoleUser,
        },
      ],
    });
```

I'm getting the error below

```
SequelizeEagerLoadingError: User is not associated to Role!
```

I've generally tried taking things out and putting back in in various combinations the defined foreign keys, other keys, aliases in the definition and varying how I call the models (removing aliases, through etc). Also I tried not specifying the referencing in the junction table.

My models and relationships are arranged on separate pages, but they're all joining up fine as I can see the 1:M relationships are working fine, it's only my M:M relationships that are messing up. I would be so grateful for any help!

Answer (score 1):

You have used through table to associate users and roles so there will be no `foreignKey` column in table role and also in users table and if you want to add `role_id` in your user table than simply create column

```
    role_id: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER(),
        allowNull: true
    }
```

than add `role_id` with other data in user table
set role like below  `user.setRoles(req.body.role_id)` this will add data in `UserRoles` table

```
Roles.belongsToMany(Users, { through: 'UserRoles', foreignKey: 'role_id', otherKey: 'user_id' });
Users.belongsToMany(Roles, { through: "UserRoles", foreignKey: "user_id", otherKey: "role_id" });
UserRoles.belongsTo(Users, { foreignKey: 'user_id', targetKey: 'id' });
UserRoles.belongsTo(Roles, { foreignKey: 'role_id', targetKey: 'id' });
```

Than try api like below to fetch all user with their roles

```
                let role = await sequelize.UserRoles.findAll({
                include: [
                    {
                        model: sequelize.Users,
                        attributes: { exclude: ['password'] }
                    },
                    {
                        model: sequelize.Roles
                    }
                ]
            });

            let result = error.OK;
            result.data = role;

            logger.info(result);
            return res.status(200).send(result)
```

Above query will return data like below

```
"data": [
    {
        "user_id": 1,
        "role_id": 2,
        "createdAt": "2020-11-11T11:40:50.999Z",
        "updatedAt": "2020-11-11T11:40:50.999Z",
        "User": {
            "id": 1,
            "first_name": "admin1",
            "last_name": "Admin1",
            "user_name": "admin1",
            "email": "admin1@gmail.com"
            "role_id": 1,
            "user_type": "ADMIN",
            "createdAt": "2020-11-11T11:40:49.053Z",
            "updatedAt": "2020-11-11T11:40:49.053Z"
        },
        "Role": {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "ADMIN"
            "createdAt": "2020-11-11T11:37:47.638Z",
            "updatedAt": "2020-11-11T11:37:47.638Z"
        }
    }
],
```

Comment: Hi Arya, thanks very much for your detailed answer but it's still not working! 
I'm now getting an error that `User is not associated to RoleUser!`

Answer (score 1):

If anyone else has this problem - the only way I could find to fix this was to state the relationship directly before using it rather than having it listed on a separate models/ relationship page.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose indicating `User` with the alias `users` is enough for your request:

```
 const roles = await Role.findAll({
      include: [
        {
          model: User,
          as: 'users'
        },
      ],
    });
```

Comment: she has used through to connect both table so there will no direct association with both table

Comment: you already connected them via `Role.belongsToMany(User` with alias `users`